# data is not populating in table using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am getting data from data base the data is coming from db and showing in alert but not showing thwe table using ng-repeat.
Here is my code :

Table Code:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
                                 <tr>
                                    <th>Doctor Id</th>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Specialization</th>
                                 </tr>
                                  <tr ng-repeat="doctor in doctorList" class="success">
                                    <td> {{doctor.userId}} </td>
                                    <td>{{doctor.name}}</td>
                                    <td>{{doctor.specialization}}</td>
                                  </tr>
                            </table>
```

Button Click Code:

```
 <div class="controls" ng-controller="searchController">
                                <a  class="btn btn-success " ng-click="searchDoctor()"> Search Doctor  </a>
                            </div>
```

Controller Code:

```
var myApp=angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('searchController',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http) {
$scope.searchDoctor = function(){
    alert("search");
    $http.get('http://localhost:8080/Webapp/webapi/doctor/'+$scope.spec).success(function(data){

        var doctorList = [];
        for(j=0; j<data.length; j++){
            alert(data[j].homeNumber);
            doctorList.push({
                "specialization" : data[j].specialization,
                "userId":  data[j].userId,
                "name":  data[j].firstName
            })
            }
        alert(doctorList[0].name);
        $scope.doctorList = doctorList;
    });
}
```

}]);

The list is set i get the value in the alert but not showing in the table.Can any one help me what i am doing wrong, I shall be thankful :)

Comment: Is your table within the div that has the search controller assigned? If not then the table's scope is not the same as the search controller.

Comment: Ideally the table should be under ng-controller="searchController" div.

Comment: @MaheshSapkal thanks it works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope of your table is in the wrong place I guess.

The table should be inside `ng-controller="searchController"` div.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have two angular controllers that are siblings like `DoctorsController` and `SearchController` and your html structure is like this?

```
<div ng-controller="DoctorsController">
    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
     ...
     </table> 
</div>
<div ng-controller="SearchController">
    ...
<div>
```

In this case it's normal that your list won't get updated because there are 2 different scopes. Maybe it's a good idea to post also your html structure including the angular controllers.